# triggerAction with RegEx and intents

Tags: node.js, botframework

I'm using the bot framework to help with basic tasks in a system. One of these tasks is listing different sets of data, such as groups and users.

The dialog that handles this looks like this:

```
lib.dialog('/', function(session) {
<code>
}).triggerAction({matches: stuff});
```

The code part can handle every type of list that is thrown at it, so I would like the triggerAction to catch all different lists. They get recognized in my own custom recognizer and will always be on the format of GetTopicList, where "Topic" is "User" or "Group" etc. So the intent will be "GetUserList" or "GetGroupList".

I can't seem to get RegEx to work since it'll start listening to the message rather than my recognizer (/^Get.*List$/ solves the problem, but it wont listen to the recognizer).

Once you use a RegEx in a triggerAction, the trigger starts listening on messages sent to the bot rather than intent, this behavior is not what I am looking for, but have the trigger still listen to intents. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the description from botbuilder nodejs source code of [MatchType](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/core/lib/botbuilder.d.ts#L42):

```
/**
 * Supported rules for matching a users utterance.
 * * _{RegExp}_ - A regular expression will be used to match the users utterance.
 * * _{string}_ - A named intent returned from a recognizer will be used to match the users utterance.
 * * _{(RegExp|string)[]}_ - An array of either regular expressions or named intents can be passed to match the users utterance in a number of possible ways. The rule generating the highest score (best match) will be used for scoring purposes. 
 */
```

So per my understanding and the result of code testing, the intents is only can be matched by sting but regexp.

I am afraid you need to use the array of string as `matches` property:

```
triggerAction({
    matches: ['GetTopicList','GetUserList',...],
})
```

Comment: I'm using a recognizer and want a RegEx to work for what the recognizer recognizes, My recognizer works such that "list users" gets recognized with the intent "GetUserList". Using a RegEx in the triggerAction switches the listener in triggerAction from intent to message. I don't want it to do that.

Comment: Modified after further testing, hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that aswell. I solved it by modifying the recognizer to have the intent "List" instead. So my dialog can have matches: 'List'. Was the best I could come up with.
Thanks for your time :)